# Make the length of "a" and "b" to be the same if they are not in R

Tags: r, function

## Background:

Suppose I have a **function** that requires the **`length` of its arguments to be exactly the same**. **But** in case a user of the function provides two unequal lengths for the two arguments:

## Question

**Is it possible that R *"shortens"* the `length` of the longer argument to be the same as the `length` of the shorter one?**

**As a schematic example**, suppose argument "a" and "b" must be of the same `length` in function `sdf` (see below). **But** I accidentally make the length of argument "b" longer. Can R evaluate the length of the shorter argument (here: "a") and then make the longer argument (here: "b") to be of the same `length` as "a"?

(Maybe R can drop from the end of "b", to make "b" to be equal in length to "a").

```
sdf = function(a, b) {

 if(length(a) != length(b)){ message("\n\tMake a and b have the same length equal")   
     
      } else {a + b}

  }

sdf(a = 2:5, b = 4:9)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming A and B are both vectors, you can chop off the end of the longer vector like so:

```
sdf = function(a, b) {
  if(length(b) > length(a)){
    b = b[1:length(a)]
  }
  else(if(length(a) > length(b)){
    a = a[1:length(b)]})
  return(a+b) #sample return operation
}



> sdf(a = 2:5, b = 4:9)
[1]  6  8 10 12


> sdf(a = 2:10, b = 3:7)
[1]  5  7  9 11 13
```

Hope this answers your question!